# Rails - Disable select_tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

How can i disable a `select_tag` like this example with javascript :

```html
<button onclick="DisableFields()">Disable</button>  

<p class="col-lg-2" id ="test1" >
   <%= 
      select_tag(:customer_service_beneficiary_id,  options_for_select(customer_service_beneficiary_col) , :class => "form-control")
   %>
</p>
```

I try this but it doesnt work :

```
function DisableFields() {
  console.log('Disable');
  $("test1").prop('disabled', true);
  $("test2").attr('disabled','disabled');
}
```

Comment: add this man :disabled=>true

Comment: you are selection is wrong test1 is for div not for the select tag

Comment: try $("select[name="name-of -select"]").attr("disabled","disabled") @Krebsmann

Comment: @uzaif you are right. Krebsmann, Can you show us the output code (not ruby tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this You are not selecting div not select

```
$('select[name="name-of-select"]').attr("disabled","disabled")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable this by the name of the select field as @uzaif said  :

```
$("select[name='select-field-name']").attr("disabled","disabled")
```